# IdentityServer4 Client Scopes and User Claims based authorization

Tags: access-token, openid-connect, identityserver4

I have an IdentityServer4 that I use for authentication/authorization and I am a little confused on how to achieve the following:

if I have let us say 2 clients, and they are trying to access 2 APIs (each client can access one of them), however I have users with different permissions (user1 can access first API, user2 can access second API, user3 can access both)

When user3 which should have access to both APIs login using first client (only api1 scope is requested by client), how will I provide him a token that grants him access to both APIs (scopes), so he should not login again when using the second client?

I have read a lot of discussions about user claims and client scopes, but still I do not have clear answer on how to use them in authenticating the above case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The client needs to request both scopes, or you need a scope that gives access to both apis.

Scopes are granted to the clients there is no way for your Ids to know that user3 should have access to both unless the client requests both scopes.

Comment: can not I apply my own logic based on my user claims stored in DB?

Comment: it does not seem logical that a client requests a client that will not be used by the same client

Comment: You can hack your own logic how ever you want.   But if i as a user authenticate an application (client) and they request access to read something and you hack logic in the back giving them access to write something. IMO you are defeating the purpose of the identity server which is to inform the user what access a client is being granted and to prevent clients from accessing data the user doesnt want them to have access to.

Comment: good point, thanks; but how can we avoid multi logins for different clients and still allow client to access only the scope it should access?

Comment: You should only have one login per user per client.   You can have different clients that request different access.   In some systems you can also expand access. so i can request read only to begin with but if later the user wants to do something that requires write access you can request additional scopes.